# .NET Core 2.x Load Referenced Assemblies, that have no type references in code

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a .NET Core 2.2 project `A`, that has **package references** to assemblies `B` and `C`. (basically NuGet referenced dlls)

I need to have `B` and `C` loaded dynamically at runtime, however I cant seem to find any documentation on how I might achieve this.

A lot of posts refer to calling `Assembly.Load()` on all referenced assemblies via `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()`, however this only retrieves assemblies, **that have some of their types explicitly referenced inside the executing assembly's code**

This does not work for me, as I dont have any refernces to their types in my code.

I found that you could get a full list of referenced assemblies, via doing a `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad()`, **however this is not supported with the .NET Core Runtime**.

I  tried searching through the `AppDomain` and `AssemblyLoadContext` classes, in order to find such information, but could not find anything useful.

So summarized, my question is **how can I dynamically load an assembly's referenced assemblies without explicitly touching some of their types in my code**?

Comment: Does your app have a list of assembly names to load?  Or are all the assemblies in the same folder?

Comment: This appears to be relevant: https://www.strathweb.com/2019/01/collectible-assemblies-in-net-core-3-0/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft My issue is getting that list. I want to load assemblies, that are set up as package references to my executing assembly. 
However I have no way of obtaining it. If i can find a way to get them, I will probably be able to load them via Assembly.Load()

Comment: And @RobertHarvey, this is kinda relevant, but its only in the previews of .NET Core 3.0. I am currently limited to .NET Core 2.x

Comment: Have you looked at the .deps.json file in your output folder?

Comment: I could try that as a last resort, but I was hoping I can get access to these dependencies via reflection. There must be some metadata within the assembly that contains its list of dependencies. I was hoping I can get to it.

Comment: Why not loop through all the dlls in the bin and load them via file path?

Comment: Unused references will be optimized out on compilation. Create a new project, add a random nuget package, compile and you will not find the nuget .dlls in the output folder nor does the resulting assembly contain an extern assembly reference at metadata level.

Comment: Publishing the app should contain them in the output, but yes - taking the output of the bin folder will not contain them. Im still hoping there is some place where this description exists

Comment: Well, grab `ildasm` and have a look yourself, but even the published assembly does not contain a single byte referencing the unused external assemblies: https://i.imgur.com/MbdaQrF.png

Comment: So, exactly 0 information is contained within the compiled output in regards to any unused, but referenced assemblies. Damn it.

Comment: @Kobek, how did you solve your issue? Running Core 3.1 here and I have the same issue.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately no. 
I made a method that returns a `Type[]` and in it, I return 1 hardcoded type for each assembly. (Using `typeof(Sometype)`). This is not used anywhere, but it's enough to force the .net compiler to include the corresponding assemblies. 

From there I use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()` to load whatever types I need from them. It's not perfect, and it only works if you know all assemblies at compile-time, but it seems to do the job for my case.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, I hope that is what you want.

You can make a window application to do it for you.
Add this package to your project:

```
Install-Package NuGet.Core -Version 2.14.0
```

After that:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string packageID = "Newtonsoft.Json"; // Use your package name
    IPackageRepository repo = PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://packages.nuget.org/api/v2");
    var version = repo.FindPackagesById(packageID).Max(p => p.Version);

    string path = "D:\\MyPackages"; // Use your path
    PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(repo, path);
    packageManager.InstallPackage(packageID, SemanticVersion.Parse(version.ToString()), true, false);
}
```

After I clicked the button, the package has been downloaded.

[image]

Comment: How is writing code to install nuget packages relevant to trying to load assemblies from code (actully reading the OPs post will tell you that he is having trouble loading the assemblies, not downloading the assemblies)